# Android ImageView Zoom with Icon

Tags: android, imageview, icons, zooming

I want to show an ImageView with an icon above it and when the user zoom the image, I want the icon to keep the same position in the image... Like the google maps icon, whenever you zoom the map the mark icon will keep the same size and position.

I'm using this library to zoom my imageView: subsampling-scale-image-view

thanks in advance,

best regards.

Comment: the images are coming from web service

Comment: Have you tried anything like - apply zoom effect on **background image** and place **icon** at fix place

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understood: I should use to image one with the image and other with the Icon and apply the zoom only on the background image? but if I do that the icon will always appear when I zoom in even if I zoom in a area where it is not supposed to appear?

Comment: set `icon.bringToFront();` and take both of the imageviews inside `Framelayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read example of your library again. It have an example with pinview as your require:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/6ae9d6ec8db21ae136e854b27b203d85cb371418/sample/src/com/davemorrissey/labs/subscaleview/sample/extension/ExtensionPinFragment.java